# React-typescript, looping over the state in reducer function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How can I loop over the whole useReducer state and set the its "isWrong" property to true if there is no value after form submission. What is the best approach to solve that. Because the problem is that I could loop over the state and make the separate variable but the problem is I need the "isWrong" property set inside state because it makes fields color red when it is wrong.

```
state = const initialStateReducer: inputsFormState = {
 title: {
    val: "",
    isValid: false,
    isClicked: false,
    isWrong: false,
  },
  description: {
    val: "",
    isValid: false,
    isClicked: false,
    isWrong: false,
  },}
```

reducer:

```
const inputReducer = (
    state: inputsFormState,
    action: inputsFormAction
  ): inputsFormState => {
    let isValid = false;
    let isClicked = true;
    let isWrong = false;
    const { content } = action;
    const validateInput = (content: string) => {
      isClicked = true;
      isValid = content.length > 0;
      isWrong = isClicked && !isValid;
    };

    if (
      action.type === ActionKind.stringVal &&
      action.field &&
      typeof content === "string"
    ) {
      validateInput(content);
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.field]: {
          val: content,
          isValid: isValid,
          isClicked: isClicked,
          isWrong: isWrong,
        },
      };
    }

Form submission
     const onSubmitHandler = (e: React.FormEvent): void => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        if (formIsValid && user?.displayName) {
          const recipe: Recipe = {
            username: user.displayName,
            title: inputsValues.description.val,
            type: type,
            description: inputsValues.title.val,
            id: Math.random(),
            time: time,
            ingredients: ingredients,
            stars: Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1,
            steps: steps,
            comments: [],
          };
          dispatch(recipeAction.addRecipe(recipe));
          dispatch(sendData(recipe));
          navigate("/");
        }
      };
```

Comment: When you say 'loop over the whole useReducer state', do you mean you want to set ```isWrong``` to false in both ```title``` and ```description``` properties?

Comment: I want to loop over the whole useReducer state, then check if value is set in title and description if not then "isWrong" is true in property which has no value. Everything has to be done on form submission.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `validateInput` arrow function to augment the state as follows:

```
const validateInput = (state: inputsFormState, content: string): inputsFormState => {
  Object.keys(state).forEach((stateKey) => {
    validatedState[stateKey] = {
      isClicked: true,
      isValid: content.length > 0,
      isWrong: isClicked && !isValid,
      val: state[stateKey].val,
    };
  });
};
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
validateInput(state, content);
return { ...state };
```

Also, if you want want `content` to be set in all of the `val` properties, you can change `val: state[stateKey].val` to `val: content`.